# Regex for copyright line

Tags: php, regex

Hello I working with php_codesniffer for our project as we are currently trying find a way to sniff out incorrect copyrights on our source files.

Currently I cant seem to get the result I looking for. We are trying to run preg_match for the following:

```
Copyright (C) 2016 - 2017 Dazzle Software, LLC. All rights reserved.
```

I tried:

```
^(Copyright (C))([0-9]{4})(-[0-9]{4})? (Dazzle Software, LLC.) \(All rights  reserved.\))$
```

but still not having much luck as I not experienced with regex or cant seem to find any good documentation on regex

Comment: many of the characters in your regex patterns are special characters (such as `.`, `-`, `(`, `)`). you will need to escape these with a \

Comment: [Did you try reading the PHP documentation?](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php)

Comment: there are a lot of sites where you can mess around with regex and get to understand how it works, such as https://regex101.com/. you might have more success in learning how regex works by breaking your string down into smaller parts and attempting to write a regular expression that matches the smaller string

Comment: Try the following /(\d+)/g

Answer (score 2):

you could use some thing like this.

```
^(Copyright \(C\)) (\d{3,4}) [-,\s] \d{4} \w*\s\w*[,-]\s\w*[.,]\s(all rights reserved)
```

here is demo : https://regex101.com/r/zF0nW9/1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test regex patterns I would suggest using a tool such as [regexr](http://regexr.com).

Here is a simple regex pattern that matches each segment of the copyright you provided:

```
^(Copyright \(C\)) (\d{4}) - (\d{4}) (Dazzle Software, LLC)\. (All rights reserved)\.
```

Where each unescaped parenthesis is a match:

```
$1 - "(Copyright \(C\))" - "Copyright (C)"
$2 - "(\d{4})" - "2016"
$3 - "(\d{4})" - "2017"
$4 - "(Dazzle Software, LLC)" - "Dazzle SOftware, LLC"
$5 - "(All rights reserved)" - "All rights reserved"
```

However if you are looking to compare with preg_match, you may want to get *any* string instead of strictly the company name, or 'All rights reserved'.

```
^(Copyright \(C\)) (\d{4}) - (\d{4}) (.+?)\. (.+?)\.
```

Where `(.+?)` will match any string non-aggressively.